# How to track 2 systems (live and testing) with git, when the software on both needs to be updated separately?

Tags: git

I'm confronted with the following situation: I have two systems with a PHP framework running on them (one is a live system, the other one is the testing system) - on each of them runs software with it's corresponding database. Both systems use the same `git` repository.

Now the problem is, that each system needs to be updated separately, because each update will perform a database update, too. If I do not update them separately and update system `A`, `git commit` and `git pull` from system `B`, the database on system `B` will not be updated and I'll have an inconsistency. On the other hand if I update them separately, I will create 2 branches from the same repo.

So how should one proceed in such a situation?

Comment: Have a third, central repo, or a pull hook on B that updates the repo when A pulls.

Answer (score 1):

If not using any tools, then making an update to a branch will not make any changes to a server.

If you are using some sort of automatic deployment tool, then you should have two separate branches, one for test and one for production as you won't want to deploy to production every time that you deploy to test in most instances. For this you may take a look Git Flow (https://leanpub.com/git-flow/read). This is a very good branching architecture from my experiance and can help keep a team on track knowing where all the code is at at any given time. Note that when I use this model I tend to change the branch names to those that work better with my team. This would allow you to point your test system deployment to the Release branch and your production system deployment to the production branch.